# How to call a function inside qw() in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a function `get_text()` which parses text from XML. I want the text with quotes also.
I tried:

```
qw($self->get_text());
```

It's actually printing `"$self->get_text()"` & not calling the function. What to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're asking. `qw/.../` is a quoting operator, the effect of which is identical to `split ' ', '...'`. If you want to split a string in the same way as `qw`, use `split`.

Comment: Pedantically, it's identical to `split ' '`, not `split /\s+/`.

Comment: @ysth: That's what's in the documentation, but the implementation actually allows any whitespace sequence. I've edited my answer to be more in line with the docs, just in case.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "just in case"?

Comment: @ysth: Just in case the implementation is updated to reflect the documentation. As if that would ever happen with Perl.

Comment: @ysth: Ah, there it is. Thanks. And once again Perl runs counter to my expectations...

Answer (score 4):

You can't use qw for that, but you can do the same whitespace splitting that qw does with:

```
@parts = split ' ', $self->get_text();
```

But your "I want the text with quotes also" makes me think you might be looking for something very different.   Can you show an example of what get_text returns and what you want it changed into?

Comment: get_text parses xml & return the text, whatever & whichever format [i.e. including quotes] & I want to save this data to a local variable. Since it contains quote, am not able to save it at the same time using qw() am not able to call that function ! this is the whole scenario.

Comment: @mandy, Perl isn't bash, and there's no difficulty in assigning a return value including quote characters to a variable.  Why do you think you need `qw()`?  What's wrong with `$var = $self->get_text()`?  You haven't successfully explained what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @mandy: I couldn't understand what you want from that.  Show what `$x` would contain if you did `$x = $self->get_text();` and then show what you want it to look like.  An example is much less confusing than a description.

Comment: $a =""@ mandy"". will it work ? no. $var = $self->get_text(), what if $self->get_text() returns a strings containing quotes.thats why am try to usw q/qw.

Comment: It doesn't matter if $self->get_text() returns quotes.  The `qw()` operator turns a set of whitespace separated tokens into a list, split on whitespace, so `qw(...)` is the same as `split " ", "..."`.  IoW, `qw(foo bar baz)` would give you a three element list: `('foo', 'bar', 'baz')`.  `qw()` is not what you need here.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confused as to what qw does, and when to use it.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators